# multiple processing does not make global counter works

Tags: python

I'm new hand and trying multiple processing to control a global counter, but the following code gave 'global_counter' 0 after join.... why?!

```
from multiprocessing import Process, RLock

global_counter = 0

def counter(n, lock):
    global global_counter
    lock.acquire()
    global_counter += n
    lock.release()

def main(process_number):
    lock = RLock()
    pr_list = []
    for i in xrange(process_number):
        pr = Process(target=counter, args=(10, lock))
        pr_list.append(pr)
    for pr in pr_list:
        pr.start()
    for pr in pr_list:
        pr.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(10)
    print global_counter # it's still 0...
```

Comment: Each process has its own private instance of the variable

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `multiprocessing.Value` object. You can remove the `RLock` object with the following implementation :

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Lock

def counter(n, shared_value, lock):
    with lock:
        shared_value.value += n

def main(process_number, shared_value):
    pr_list, lock = [], Lock()
    for i in xrange(process_number):
        pr = Process(target=counter, args=(10, shared_value, lock))
        pr_list.append(pr)

    for pr in pr_list:
        pr.start()
    for pr in pr_list:
        pr.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    shared_counter = Value("i", 0)
    main(10, shared_counter)
    print shared_counter.value # 100
```

This happens because 2 processes does not share the memory. The child process will have his own copy of the memory, and will not update the original `global_counter` variable.

However, threads share the memory.

Comment: Hi, Funky I tried your code just copied to my Sublime, and still 0~ anything wrong?

Comment: That sounds strange. It works fine for me ; are you sure you didn't modify anything ? What is your Python version (normally, it would work anyway)

Comment: python 2.6 on linux, it's 100.

Comment: python 2.7.6 on windows, it's 0.

Comment: Ok by looking on google, I discovered the following : http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/04/shared-counter-with-pythons-multiprocessing I'll edit. I don't have any windows to test, so please tell me if there's another issue.

Comment: It works on my Windows (Python 2.7.8). If my answer helped, please consider validating it :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a profound difference between `threading` and `multiprocessing`.

Basically, threads are part of the same process and *share* all data, while multiple processes as used by `multiprocessing` all have their own data (which is a copy of the parent process on the moment the new process started). So each child process has its own independant `global_counter`. Using a `Value` as suggested by FunkySayu is a good solution in this case.

Another point of interest is that in CPython, the Global Interpreter Lock *enforces* that only one thread at a time is executing Python bytecode. This means that processor-intensive tasks will not benefit as much from threading as expected. Spreading the processing out over multiple problems (using `multiprocessing`) avoids this issue. On the other hand, the results from the calculations done in separate processes usually have to be transported back to the parent process. Depending on the size of that data, this also has overhead.